# Getting a constant number from a pointer to an address in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, testing, casting

I am working with some embedded code but have to run the unit tests in Linux on the desktop. In the embedded code I am using a fixed memory address but cannot use this same address/number in Linux.

So in the embedded code/device I have code in this form:

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        const static uint64_t ADDRESS_TO_USE = 0xdeadbeef;
```

I am trying
to fix this using code of this form:

```
uint8_t bigLumpOfMemory[0x100000];

class MockFoo
{
    private:
        const static uint64_t ADDRESS_TO_USE = reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t>(&bigLumpOfMemory[0]);
```

But this fails as I am not able to use a cast in such an expression (I believe). Is there a canonical way round this?

**Edit** the compiler error is:

```
error: conversion from pointer type ‘uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}’ to arithmetic type ‘uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}’ in a constant-expression
```

Comment: what is the full and complete compiler error?

Comment: Edited and added above

Comment: Where is the `constexpr`?

Comment: I am attempting to assign to a constant. I am not using constexpr anywhere

Comment: The compiler error says "in a constant-expression". But there's no contexpr in the code, and it also compiles fine on godbolt.

Comment: What is your compiler, and what are you compiler settings (command line arguments etc).

Comment: Addresses are only available after linking, so it looks like in most compilers you can't take that address as a constant. I got the above error in gcc but MSVC and 32-bit Clang also fail to compile that: https://godbolt.org/z/a17K1eK6j

Comment: would you like to write that as an answer and I'll accept it?